# Sitecore Intranet Login ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx

Tags: authentication, sitecore, returnurl, sitecore-intranet-portal

My Sitecore Intranet Portal used to work fine, and i haven't done any changes to my site in days, but suddenly when i try to go to my frontpage i will get a blank "Untitled Page" at this location:

```
"/forms/IntranetLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx"
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Hello Kasper,  I think that you will have explain in more detail your problem in order to get an answer.  For example what do you mean by SIP as this term can mean a wide number of things?

Comment: Sitecore Intranet Portal. :). I will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by our Intranet not being able to connect to the LDAP database (our database with users). Someone changed the password to the database without telling, we changed it now and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have presentation information on your home item? Also, do you see this "Default page" right on the page with URL you supplied, or you are redirected to another page?

Comment: What do you mean by "presentation information" ?                    When i enter my intranet URL, i am redirected to this location: "intraneturlhere/forms/IntranetLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx" and i get a blank "Untitled Page".

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made any changes to your content or Sitecore configuration, was there perhaps a Windows Update that fouled things up? Double check that ASP.NET is properly configured and enabled. What version of IIS are you running on?

Comment: Everything seems to be configured properly and enabled. I can't seem to find anything wrong and we are running IIS version 6.

Comment: Do other .NET pages run on the site without issue? Double check that ASP.NET v2.0 is Allowed under Web Service Extensions in IIS Manager.

Comment: ASP.net is working fine, the admin part is running without problems.